# Separate link_to with comma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to separate this block with commas :

```
  - game_publication.groups.each_with_index do |group, index|
    = link_to store_group_path(current_store, group) do
      %span= @groups.find(group).name.to_s + (index > 0 ? ', ' : '')
```

But for the moment it returns something like

```
<label>Groups :</label>
  <a href="/66-store/groups/4594?locale=en">
    <span>party hard</span>
  </a>
  <a href="/66-store/groups/5063?locale=en">
    <span>b0m,</span>
  </a>
  <a href="/66-store/groups/5066?locale=en">
    <span>test,</span>
  </a>
</label>
```

It doesn't seems a situation where I can use any rails helpers.

I would like something like **group1, group2, group3**.

```
<label>Groups :</label>
  <a href="/66-store/groups/4594?locale=en">
    <span>party hard,</span>
  </a>
  <a href="/66-store/groups/5063?locale=en">
    <span>b0m,</span>
  </a>
  <a href="/66-store/groups/5066?locale=en">
    <span>test</span>
  </a>
</label>
```

Comment: how you want to create a link

Comment: @RORDeveloper ? Everything works expect the comma.

Comment: so your logic is wrong with the `index>0` part, is that the only problem? :/

Comment: Yes @sevenseacat. I have "group1 group2, group3," and I want "group1, group2, group3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, are you sure that you pasted here the *exact* code which gave the posted result? In your code, you have

```
(index > 0 ? '' : ',')
```

which means: *Do not add a comma UNLESS we are on the first element*. The result you posted had the comma the otherway round: It has a comma everywhere, EXCEPT for the first element. With other words: The code you posted, can't produce the output you posted.

Now for your problem: You want to add a comma on every element, except the last. This means that you need to know the highest (last) index value:

```
last_index = game_publication.groups.size - 1
```

With this, you can write your expression as

```
(index == last_index ? '' : ',')
```